# The continuous image of a countable union of closed sets can be represented by a countable union of closed sets

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^k$.
>
> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^l$ be a continuous function.
>
> Prove there exist a countable set of closed sets $C_n$ in
> $\mathbb{R}^l$ such that $f(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = \cup_{n=1}^\infty C_n$.

The only direction that really seemed to lead me somewhere fruitful was to create a countable union of closed balls in $f(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)^o$ (by finding $y_1$ and $\epsilon_1$ such that $\overline{B}(y_1,\epsilon) \subseteq f(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)^o$, then if it's not all of $f(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)^o$ there must be another internal point $y_2$ not in that ball and a corresponding $\epsilon_2$ etc...).

The problem is that I'm still left with the boundary elements of $f(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)^o$ that are in $f(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$.

Obviously, I haven't used the fact that $f$ is continuous at all or that $A_n$ are closed, but I cannot see how these two can help with accounting for the aforementioned boundary elements.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that the continuous image of a COMPACT set is compact? If so, then simply observe (and explain why) each closed set is a countable union of compact sets, hence a countable union of closed sets is a countable union of $\ldots$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Oh - I see now that you meant for each $A_n$ to be split into a union of compact sets -- will have a go with that. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro is this property of closed sets limited to spaces where closed balls are compact? (For metric spaces that is)

Comment: @Carlyle: I don't know what properties (presumably context of topological spaces, and not more generally) imply that every closed set in the space is a $\sigma$-compact set, but almost certainly something more general than a metric space has this property. Moreover, it might be the case that this property doesn't hold, but instead we have something just as good, namely every closed set is a $\sigma$-$C$ set, where each $C$ set (a made up name) has the property that a continuous image of a $C$-set is a $C$-set and the intersection of a $C$-set with a closed set is a closed set.

Comment: I think the stuff about $C$-sets doesn't quite work, I'm not sure at the moment (I'm a bit brain-dead from working on something else all day and I just stopped for the day), but at least it will give you an idea of how one might go about generalizing/creating something in math -- look carefully at exactly what is required to make the proof work, and then use what is needed to formulate your definitions in an "operational way", then seek something concrete that satisfies them.